# How to Convert Lead into Person Account and Opportunity only thorugh sfdc customization like Apex or any other way?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

Is there any way to convert Lead into Person Account, Opportunity only not contact if Lead record has  has company name.

I have gone through lead conversion process on Salesforce Documentation as per salesforce documentation Lead if has no company is converted into Person account but I want to convert Lead into person account if it has company values on Lead.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that's possible. As mentioned, person accounts are created when there is no company. Where would you want to store the company info after conversion? You could clear the value from the lead then convert and set the value from company wherever you want to place it via apex. You might want to consider creating a custom field on the lead to store the info as well. Also, in my experience, I wanted to get as far away from person accounts as possible... But if it's working for you that's great.

Comment: I don't follow you. "company" is a required field on lead. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, it is required field on page layout of lead so we can change it. But my requirement is either company field is empty or not, I want to convert it into person account & opportunity.

Comment: @zainogi has the right approach to explore - you're going to need a shadow field on Lead to hold the company name so you can null out (via workflow) `Lead.company`. Your custom Lead.ShadowCompany__c field can be mapped to a custom field on the Person Account that with an additional trigger/process builder/workflow you can 'move out of the shadows'.